# Out-of-process memory heap to work around 32-bit address space

Tags: c++, winapi, ipc, out-of-memory

Problem: A large-scale simulation game has a ridiculous number of distinct objects which have to be tracked, updated, and used for both visual rendering and for logical model updating. With only 4 GB of address space, you can only fit so many things into memory. If you resort to disk, things start to slow down unless you get lucky and are constantly hitting the page cache. But even then, making a lot of updates/writes is going to be costly when the filesystem syncs to disk.

Let's assume the user has at least 32GB of RAM (a few have reported 64) and wants to play an enormous simulation, causing the model to carry around an order of magnitude more data than most of the stuff the game has been developed to handle. They of course have a 64-bit OS (let's say, Windows 7 x64 or Windows 8 x64). Naturally, if you just store all of this model data in virtual address space in-process, even with Large Address Aware you're going to run into an out of memory situation, even if the host has gigabytes and gigabytes of free *RAM* (because the 32-bit process is out of *Virtual Address Space* (VAS)).

Let's also assume that, for reasons entirely out of your control, you can't make the main binary 64-bit. You depend on some proprietary framework, have spent ridiculous man hours coding to that framework, and would have to start over from square one to move to something else. Your framework only ships a 32-bit version, so you're stuck.

Right?

Maybe.

I had a random thought, and it seems like a long shot, because I don't know if I could make it efficient or practical.

If I could create a child 64-bit process, it would be able to use, for all practical purposes, as much RAM as anyone today can afford to buy and slot into a motherboard, even on a very high-end server chassis.

Now, I want to be able to *efficiently* store and retrieve large chunks of data from the model that's been shoved into the child process, and get subsections of that data copied into the child process from time to time. So basically, the "main" model in all its gigabytes of glory (a series very huge tree-ish and hashtable-ish structures) will sit in the 64-bit process, and the 32-bit process will peek in there, grab a hunk of data, do stuff with it (or maybe I should ask the child process to do some processing in there to distill it down??), then get rid of it -- to keep the memory usage manageable in the 32-bit process.

All the model read/mutate/simulate algorithms are based around the assumption that the model is available locally in-process, so things like random array access are common. It would be hard for me to distill down my access patterns to a few chunk-based sequential reads from the main model, and a walk of the whole model isn't terribly uncommon either.

My goals are:

- Keep the darn thing from crashing due to out of memory (#1 goal)
- Performance (a very close #2, but people using an extreme amount of complexity may come to accept worse performance than those simulating a smaller, simpler game)
- Minimal refactoring of the existing code (more or less vanilla C++ with rendering calls and multithreading)

It seems like a pretty hefty project to even undertake, since going from a coherent memory model to having to essentially look through an aperture at a much larger model than I can grab at any one time will probably necessitate a lot of algorithm redesign.

My questions:

- Is there any precedent for doing this?
- *How* would this best be done on Windows? Is there some kind of shared memory like on Linux, or lightweight very high-bandwidth random memory access IPC that can be integrated into C++ via something like an `operator[]()` implementation?
- Is the performance of any IPC going to be so bad that it's not even worth trying? Should I just rely on the disk (you know, databases or key-value or whatever) and let the operating system / filesystem figure out how to use the RAM?

Keep in mind that I'd need support for an *extremely* "chatty" IPC mechanism, because a lot of the processing algorithms (AI, etc) are designed around small memory accesses and updates. This works well enough in-process, and there is even some attention towards cache locality, but all that turns weird when you are accessing it over IPC.

Comment: Why don't you just make your main program 64 bit?  For them to use your child process they need to run a 64 bit OS and hardware anyway, why complicate things?  And how likely are they to run a 32 bit OS with more than 4 GB of RAM these days?

Comment: @GabeSechan Please read the third paragraph. When you have things of this complexity, "just making the main program 64-bit" can mean switching to a new engine and dumping *man-years* of work. This would be a likelihood for a future project, but not for the current one.

Comment: 1) Have you tried using multi-threaded out-of-core streaming from HD before criticizing it? 2) What if I don't have 32GB of RAM and don't want to buy it, does that mean I can't be the user of your software? In other words, are you sure all your customers are willing to install so much RAM?

Comment: 1) No, not yet. Right now everything is taking place in memory, and the only problem that's encountered is, if the model gets too complex, you run out of VAS. 2) For smaller-scale simulations, I don't see a problem keeping the existing program running where it doesn't do any kind of shared memory hack. The existing program has very low overhead for in-process memory reads/writes to update the model, but the 32-bit VAS limits the scale. The "alternate mode" would have higher overhead read/write but the scale could increase by orders of magnitude.

Comment: I'd see if it's possible to instead move the 32-bit framework into a subordinate 32-bit process OR compile it and virtualize/emulate it in the 64-bit process.

Comment: "Address Windowing Extensions" makes it possible to use memory more than 4g in a 32-bit process. It seems to be only available on windows of server edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in a similar situation to you, GUI was 32bit but needed x64 code to interface with a system. The approach we took was to use **WM_COPYDATA** and pass data back and forth across the magical process bit boundary. Naturally, it is not as fast as using a dll, but that was not an option. The performance tradeoff was acceptable for our use case.

Answer (score 1):

*If  understand you correctly.*

If you use multiple processes then windows will still need to page the sections in and out.

This is how I'd envisage trying it.

Use [memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/dd997372.aspx) to map a view/section of the memory space persisted on disk that you need. You of course will need to have some internal mapping scheme to.

The key thing that I don't know at this point is whether you can access the 64 bit API from 32 bits.

Windows will take care of the paging magically and efficiently. This is what it does for memory mapping virtual memory anyway. We used to use it to work with massive datasets on  the early 32 bit NT systems and the technology just works.

Comment: You mean a "Non-persisted memory-mapped file" (this terminology taken from the link you provided)? Isn't that basically just an in-process buffer? If the process is 32-bit, that doesn't help much...

Comment: My last journey with memory mapped files on Windows ended up with unhappy discovery that it has limitations in terms of file size. For instance, after mapping files exceeding ~600MB it started to crash randomly.

Comment: @Haroogan I would expect exactly that behavior to occur, since you are running out of VAS. This just begs the question in my original post. The data would have to be persistently stored in a file (or somewhere else, *like another process*) and then have an "aperture" into a subset of that file to map it into memory. I'm trying to get away from using the disk, because this model has a completely separate serialization process and it's updated so often that it isn't normally stored on disk during operation as it's currently designed.